# SQL - All values from first table joined with first value from second one and null otherwise

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

is it possible to do a join like this in SQL:

[image: Sessions and Pageviews]

We want to join the two tables on SessionID, but the resulting table should return full table "Pageviews" combined with only **a single** value of Sessions for each unique SessionID (for others the value should be NULL, please see the 'Desired Result' table for explanation).

Thank you.

Comment: Define _first match_!

Comment: Put another way: How does the database engine know what the "first" record is in PageViews?  why was 34 chosen and not 36 for FA-1?  Keep in mind order in a table isn't guaranteed.  So do you always want the record with the lowest pageViews?  the highest?  How do we handle ties?  D-Shih's response is how I would handle this but we don't know what order by to assign in the rownum() analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
SELECT T2.SessionID,T2.pageviews,T1.Sessions
FROM sessions AS T1
RIGHT JOIN 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sessionid ORDER BY sessionid DESC) AS ROWNUM,
         sessionid,
         pageviews
  FROM pageviews
) AS T2
ON T1.sessionid = T2.sessionid AND T2.ROWNUM = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5424d/5)

Answer (score 2):

Based on you requirement( and truly based on the data provided) the below code would do the work -

```
declare @pageviews table(sessionid char(10), pageviews tinyint)
declare @sessions table(sessionid char(10), sessions tinyint)
insert into @pageviews values
('FA-1',34),
('FA-1',36),
('FA-2',23),
('FA-3',11),
('FA-3',32),
('FA-3',25)
insert into @sessions values
('FA-1',23),
('FA-2',14),
('FA-3',9)

;with cte as
(select sessionid,pageviews,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sessionid ORDER BY sessionid desc) rn
from @pageviews)
select p.sessionid,p.pageviews,case when rn = 1 then s.sessions else null end as sessions
from cte p inner join @sessions s
on p.sessionid = s.sessionid
```